# Groupby, sum, reset index & keep first all together

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using the following code and my goal is to group by 2 columns (out of tens of them), then keep the first value of all the other columns while summing the values of two other columns. And it doesn't really work no matter the combination that I tried.

Code used:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['col_1', 'Col_2'], as_index = False)[['Age', 'Income']].apply(sum).first()
```

The error that I am getting is the following which just leads me to believe that this can be done with a slightly different version of the code that I used.

```
TypeError: first() missing 1 required positional argument: 'offset'
```

Any suggestions would be more than appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide some sample code for starting df and expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `agg` with configuring corresponding functions for each column.

```py
group = ['col_1', 'col_2']
(df.groupby(group, as_index=False)
 .agg({
    **{x: 'first' for x in df.columns[~df.columns.isin(group)]}, # for all columns other than grouping column
    **{'Age': 'sum', 'Income': 'sum'} # Overwrite aggregation for specific columns
 })
)
```

This part `{ **{...}, **{...} }` will generate

```py
{
   'Age': 'sum',
   'Income': 'sum',
   'othercol': 'first',
   'morecol': 'first'
}
```

Comment: Works great, thanks a lot!. Could you give more context regarding the "# Overwrite aggregation for specific columns" comment so I can have a better understanding of what exactly is being overwritten.

Comment: Cool.   The first line of `**{x: 'first' ...}`, this line is not excluding 'Age' or 'Income' so, this line creates `{'Age': 'first', 'Income': 'first', 'othercol': 'first', ...}`.  Then, second line of `**{...}`, will overwrite value by the key, resulting the 'Age' and 'Income''s value is `'sum'`, other columns remains as `'first'`.   You can exclude the 'Age' and 'Income' in the first line as well.  That should not change the output.

Comment: Some simple demo you can try.  `{**{'a': 1, 'b': 1}, **{'a': 2}}`.  Check what dictionary this code will end up with.  (a is 1? or 2?)